# Responsive table - Limiting text in specific cell to one line on dektop?

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-table

I'm trying to make the second cell on my table `width: 100%;` and the text to stay on one line.

The mobile version is working OK, but I can't find a solution for desktop version because the last cells won't collapse the text in the second cell.

Link: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/rmm/full/pNMomP/)

*Also, this kinda worked:*

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

*But made all the cells widths even. (I want the second cell to be full width and the rest of the cells to adapt to the content that's inside)*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use your `th` to set the col's width:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 20px auto;
  table-layout: fixed;/* will also fix width to cells if specified */
  width: 100%;
}
table thead tr th {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
table thead tr th,
table tbody tr td {
  padding: 10px;
}
table tbody tr td {
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
table tbody tr,
table thead tr {
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
/* set th width */
table thead tr th:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  width: 2em;/* should be enough*/
}

/* LAST TWO CELLS */

table thead tr th:nth-child(2) ~th {
  width: 4em;/* should be enough*/
}
/* end th width */

table tbody tr td:first-child {
  text-align:right;
  padding:0 0.25em 0 0
}

/* SECOND CELL */

table tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
table tbody tr td:nth-child(2) ~td {
  background: red;
  text-align:center;
}
/* RESPONSIVE */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  table thead {
    display: none;
  }
  table tbody tr {
    display: block;
  }
  table tbody tr td {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e5e7;
  }
  table tbody tr td:first-child {
    background: #f8f8f8;
  }
  table tbody tr td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0px;
  }
  table tbody tr td:before {
    content: attr(data-th);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Post Title</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-th="POST ID: ">1</td>
        <td data-th="TITLE: ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
        <td><a href="#">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-th="POST ID: ">01</td>
        <td data-th="TITLE: ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
        <td><a href="#">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-th="POST ID: ">150</td>
        <td data-th="TITLE: ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
        <td><a href="#">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="#">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow! That's great thanks! Do you know if it's possible to make the first column adapt to the content instead of making the width fixed? Because the ID column is going to have more than 1 digit soon so it's not going to fit in the fixed cell. If not, I will just remove this colum. Thanks again!

Comment: @RMM if you do not set a width, it will share evenly space with other cells with unspecified width. you need to set a safe width . 2em should allow a few digits

Answer (score 0):

Unsure the end goal, but when i run into issues like this, I typically create psuedo-tables out of divs rather than using tables. This will allow you to manipulate the block positioning much more freely than you can with table cells.

Comment: I see, I will probably do this if I don't find a solution. Thanks!